# allocating space for pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Assuming I have a pointer `ptr` and I allocate some space for that pointer. Now, if I have another pointer `ptr2` and do this:

```
ptr2 = ptr;
```

Does this mean I allocate space for `ptr2` or do I need to allocate for `ptr2` by myself?

Comment: You should accept an answer if one of the available ones solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, depends what you mean by "allocate space for a pointer".

For example:

```
int* ptr;
```

allocates space for the pointer in automatic memory. The pointer doesn't point to anything meaningful though. If you did:

```
int* ptr = new int;
```

you have space allocated in automatic memory for the pointer itself, and that pointer points to the memory allocated by `new int`, which is in dynamic memory.

If now you did:

```
int* ptr2 = ptr;
```

you have some memory in automatic memory for `ptr2` itself, **but it will point to the same location in dynamic memory as `ptr`**.

So in the end, you have allocated memory for 2 `int*`s in automatic storage, and for one `int` in dynamic storage. The two pointers point to the same memory.

The automatic memory is cleaned up automatically (duuh). You have to delete the dynamically allocated memory yourself:

```
delete ptr;
```

Note that since the two point to the same location, so:

```
delete ptr;
delete ptr2;
```

would yiled undefined behavior (so is illegal).

(this is all subject to optimizations, but, in principle, it goes down like this)

Answer (score 2):

You don't "allocate space for a pointer". You only "allocate space", and then you have a pointer to that space. In your case, you simply have two pointers (`ptr` and `ptr2`) to the same space.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is just like a simple variable, with just a difference that it stores a memory address. So there are two kinds of space allocations that need to be considered. One is the space that the pointer variable itself takes. The second is the space to which the pointer points. As the question says,

> Assume I have a pointer `ptr` and I allocate some space for that pointer

I consider it to be talking of the second case.

So, when you do `ptr2 = ptr`, `ptr2` points to the same space as pointed to by `ptr`. However, yes some space is allocated for ptr2, where it can store the address to which it points.

Comment: Pointers also need space. See Luchian Grigore's answer.

Comment: Well, as his answer says, depends on what you mean by "allocate space for a pointer". Two aspects are here to be considered, whether you are talking about the space where pointer is stored or the memory to which it points.

Comment: @shrey347 regardless of what he means by "allocate space for a pointer", your first statement "You dont actually allocate a space for a pointer" is false, since the pointer takes up space itself.

Comment: Well, if you take it literally, yes the statement is false. Contextually, i don't think it is. But yes, if it conveys false information, am changing it to what would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is like a variable or POD (plain old datatype, e.g. int), with the difference that it holds a memory address. All you're doing is to copy/assign the address from one variable to another.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler allocates memory for all variables referenced in your program. Let's say a pointer is a kind of variable.

So, there is memory allocated for ptr1 and ptr2:

Both pointers are pointing to NULL:

```
ptr          ptr2 
0x0        | 0x0
```

Each pointer is pointing to a memory address where a value is stored:

```
ptr          ptr2
0x0F032010 | 0x0C012A10
```

ptr2 is now pointing to the same value as ptr. Whatever was pointed by ptr2 is lost.

```
ptr          ptr2
0x0F032010 | 0x0F032010
```

To answer your question, ptr2 = ptr does not create a copy of the value pointed by ptr, it just make the variable ptr2 able to access the same value as ptr.